# Minimize cost for Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-cloud-services

I have an Azure Cloud Service published at Microsoft and it's draining all my credit!

**Payment**

Pay as you go

**Service resource**

Minimal resource, 1 SMALL web role and 1 SMALL  worker role.

I knew Azure wasn't cheap, but this is just too much. Currently my monthly cost is just under 80 USD. The only person that use this service is me, noone else, and I barely use it. So the cost is just for the upkeep.

**Is this normal?**

70 bucks a month!?
How much does it cost for YOU?

**What Microsoft support told me**

> I am afraid the Cloud Services has a fixed price, and I am not aware
>   how it could be lowered. Maybe you want to check on how the service
>   itself could be tweaked to get it working as per your needs. You may
>   want to go through the Community Forum for that.

Community = Stackoverflow, so here I am!

If I look at my Azure subscription page I can see that it's the:

**CALCULATING HOURS - Europe, Western**

That is taking all my hard earned money. My service also uses SQL, storage and cache but, if I understand it correctly, these are not the cause for my expensive bill.

Before I leave you to it I just want to say that I can't use a simple web app because of my requirements. I know web apps are super cheap, but in this case I must use a cloud service..

Thank you

**Update**

I found out I was using A1 (small) and not A0 (extra small). The instance type for a cloudservice can be set in the servicedefinition file.

It's sad that not even Microsoft themselves could inform me about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web and worker roles are like dedicated VMs if they are *on*, they will cost you money.

You can do one of two things

1) Stop the machines when no one is using them ( say in the off business hours). I am not sure if this is possible to do or not in your case. But if it is possible, you can run a small script to start/ stop the roles. You can even do so via apps on your phone. For example  - https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/azure-management/id826446897?mt=8

2) Move to Azure Web Apps and Azure Web Jobs  - Both these services are "multi-tenant" and cost much less and in fact offer a free tier. If and when you need to scale, you can always scale as your need

Hope this helps

Comment: Okey just as I thought. I was also wondering how much other people are paying for their cloud service and how much a normal monthly cost is. I know can look at the azure pricing calculator but i would rather hear from other users and their experience.

Comment: Assuming regular price without discounts I pay ~60 $ month for a single A1  ( 1 core, ~2 GB, 225 GB Disk) sized web role for the entire month  ( 730 hours).   A0 instance would be even cheaper. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I have never seen an option for these A0.. Where do you downgrade from A1 to A0?

Comment: @VishwasLele one correction - AFAIK, stopping Cloud Services will continue to incur charges. I believe this is true for Virtual Machines and not Cloud Services. For Cloud Services, only option to stop being charged is to delete the deployment completely.

Comment: You are right. Thanks!  @Reft you will need to delete and recreate the cloud service in order to stop and start accruing charges.